# Using the fontWithSize API with San Francisco

Tags: ios, fonts, ios9, uifont, uifontdescriptor

The new San Francisco fonts in iOS 9 are optimized for the size it will be used at, by adjusting tracking and dynamically switching between SF Display and SF Text. It was noted in the WWDC session #804 developers should not use San Francisco by attempting to initialize a `UIFont` using `fontWithName`, for example:

```
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithName:originalFont.fontName size:44];
```

This is because the system cannot optimize the font for the new size when using the `fontWithName` API.

Instead it was recommended to get the `UIFontDescriptor` from the original font and create a new font from that at the new size, like so:

```
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
UIFont *newFont = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:originalFont.fontDescriptor size:44];
```

However, they did not mention if the following allows for optimizations or not:

```
UIFont *originalFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:11];
UIFont *newFont = [originalFont fontWithSize:44];
```

My question is, does the `fontWithSize` API behave like the `fontWithName` API or the `fontWithDescriptor` API - does it result in an optimized font for the new size or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can confirm `fontWithSize` does create an optimized font at the new size.

```
Printing description of originalFont:
<UICTFont: 0x7f8d9ba85340> font-family: ".SFUIText-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 11.00pt

Printing description of newFont:
<UICTFont: 0x7f8d9ba7fe70> font-family: ".SFUIDisplay-Regular"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 44.00pt
```